# Android server not available at http://localhost:8080/wd/hub from the host machine

Tags: c#, selenium, android-emulator

I am in the means of setting up of android drivers and followed the same steps as mentioned in the url : http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

1) downloaded the android SDK for windows and unpacked and placed in the path of  selenium repository
2) Set up the emulator and created the new AVD ( android virtual device )
3)Installed the webdriver apk
4)port forwarding in order to forward traffic from the host machine to the emulator. In a terminal type:

$./adb -s  forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080

5) This will make the android server available at //localhost:8080/wd/hub from the host machine.

But when i went to localhost:8080/wd/hub it displayed error 404 : not found

Let me know why this is happening ? anything i missed ?

When taps on webdriver in android emulator it says webdriver ready but not displaying message as Jetty started.. can you also let me know why Jetty is not started ?

And I got some Selenium C# tests and changed to android driver from firefox , when i compiled and ran it got the same webdriver exception : 404 not found

Can you please help. thanks

Comment: try using ipnumber instead of localhost

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. But can you please explain more in details how i need to use ipnumber and how to find android access to a site hosted by a local web server. And how to know the emulator use which address to use the local web service. when i try after port forwarding getting error 404 : not found. Address i browsed http://localhost:8080/wd/hub. Can you please help

Comment: Hi It says webdriver started in the android emulator , but not saying Jetty started......  i need to install anyother thing to get Jetty started ? Can you please help

Comment: replace localhost with your computers ip number(google how) for example: 192.168.0.1:8080/wd/hub

Comment: But the issue is Jetty not get started ( not displayed in emulator as Jetty started )
I tried to replace with ipaddress but not wo
And the android server not available at localhost:8080/wd/hub from the host machine. ( tried using ipaddress also .. no joy )

When I ran my test by changing to driver = new AndroidDriver();

Failure: SetUp : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error.

Error 404 Not Found

HTTP ERROR: 404 Problem accessing /hub/session. Reason: Not Found Powered by Jetty://

TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here's how I managed to solve it.

- I got the SDK from macupdate. You may also download it from the official site
- Unzipped it to my repo and also symlinked to my home folder. So it looks like:

  ```
  /Volumes/repo/android_sdk
  ~/android_sdk -> /Volumes/repo/android_sdk
  /Volumes/repo/selenium
  ```

Note - selenium source http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/checkout

- To make it convenient, I moved android-server-2.21.0.apk to ~/android_sdk and here's how I setup the emulator:

  ```
  ~/android_sdk/tools/android update sdk --no-ui
  ~/android_sdk/tools/android create avd -n my_android -t 12 -c 100M
  ~/android_sdk/tools/emulator -avd my_android &
  ~/android_sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 -e install -r  ~/android_sdk/android-server-2.21.0.apk
  ~/android_sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.openqa.selenium.android.app/.MainActivity
  ~/android_sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
  ```
- I did not see "Jetty Started"
- Your problem mentioned C# but it has nothing to do with the issue. I use python; so:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  android = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:8080/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.ANDROID)
  android.get("http://google.com")
  ```

Voila!